# Share value between child and parent view in SwiftUI MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm trying to write an app using SwiftUI and the MVVM architecture. I understand how a view is automatically updated when its view model changes, but I don't get how I can access that view model in a parent view. For example, I have this view which contains a text field with a red background:

```
class CustomTextFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = "abc"
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CustomTextFieldViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .frame(height: 50)
            TextField("Enter text...", text: $viewModel.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my main content view with an instance of this CustomTextField as well as a Text that's supposed to reference the text field's text:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textFieldModel = CustomTextFieldViewModel()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(viewModel: $viewModel.textFieldModel)
            TextField("type", text: $viewModel.textFieldModel.text)
        }
    }
}
```

When I first launch the app, the Text label does show the initial value of "abc", but when I type in the text field this doesn't update.
How can I "synchronise" these both?

Answer (score 0):

Here is fix

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(viewModel: viewModel.textFieldModel) // << fix !!
            Text("\(viewModel.textFieldModel.text)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up fixing it. It was not only that, but the `viewModel` in `CustomTextField` should've been a @Binding as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by doing this:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textFieldModel = CustomTextFieldViewModel()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(viewModel: $viewModel.textFieldModel)
            Text("\($viewModel.textFieldModel.text.wrappedValue)") //<< wrappedValue
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class CustomTextFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = "abc"
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @Binding var viewModel: CustomTextFieldViewModel //<< @Binding

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .frame(height: 50)
            TextField("Enter text...", text: $viewModel.text)
        }
    }
}
```